# Justification for running Active Directory in a development environment

Tags: windows, active-directory, development

I currently work in a department focusing on developing software on the .Net platform. They come from a linux/php setting and have moved as a team onto the Windows world.

The team have set up a nice CI system, based on heterogeneous systems for source control, build server etc. (6-7 systems). Each one contains its own isolated user management, resulting in new developers/consultants have to be created and managed in each system.

What I am looking for is some nice cost/benifit justifications for rolling out an AD in the department.

Personally I find that AD is ubiquitous in the Windows world, but that in itself is not enough argumentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are numerous advantages of running AD, all of which you can easily research for yourself.  If you already have a Windows Server OS in the development environment, then there is no cost.

Comment: Might SO be a better place to ask this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about being forced into a Windows development environment. However, if you look at expanding beyond some number of computers (you choose the pain threshold), then at some point look at the labor of adding a user in one place via AD vs. adding the same user at n computers. Of course, we won't mention the time when you get the user typo'ed and then have to go back and fix.

In addition, when you start to get security requirements levied down (see [STIGs](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx)) you will need to have a central place to manage users. Now what happens when a developer leaves? If a user comes and goes for 10 computers and updating takes 10 minutes (hey, you have to log on too), then AD will take 20 minutes, and without AD it will take 200 minutes. If labor cost is $200/hr, then with AD is $67 and without is $667. Now add 10 users...

The next reason is to use AD integrated tools.  If you use JIRA or SVN, there's some nice integration tools so you don't have to manage accounts there -- they use the AD accounts already set up. ...and so on...

Comment: You make a good point for *a* central system, but no clear reason as why that would be AD. Might be nice to expand on that. And the team might already have their own central authentication server. (Which may or may not integrate nicely with .net).